# clientSecret isn't reaching the front end (Vercel, supabase, stripe)

Tags: stripe-payments

There are no errors but the problem that I'm having is that the page won't get out of "Loading..." because clientSecret is not properly reaching the front end (from stripe to server to front end). It shouldn't be a problem with rendering the page because of the loading feature I added. I have checked my .env.local and everything looks correct there too.

At the moment, I am checking for Client Secret Fetching: Ensuring that the clientSecret is being correctly fetched from the backend. The useEffect hook in PaymentsPage component may be responsible for this.

Front end code

```
"use client"

import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements, useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY || '');

// Define the packages
const packages = [
  { id: 'basic-001', name: 'Basic Package', description: 'Basic service offering.' },
  { id: 'standard-002', name: 'Standard Package', description: 'Enhanced features included.' },
  { id: 'premium-003', name: 'Premium Package', description: 'All features plus premium support.' },
  { id: 'exclusive-004', name: 'Exclusive Package', description: 'All premium features with exclusive benefits.' }
];

const PaymentsPage = () => {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined); // Changed from null to undefined
  const [selectedPackage, setSelectedPackage] = useState(packages[0].id); // Moved up here

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('/api/checkout_sessions', { packageId: selectedPackage })
      .then(response => {
        setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }, [selectedPackage]); // Now depends on selectedPackage

  return (
    clientSecret ? (
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
        <CheckoutForm 
          selectedPackage={selectedPackage} 
          setSelectedPackage={setSelectedPackage}
        />
      </Elements>
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  );
};

type CheckoutFormProps = {
  selectedPackage: string;
  setSelectedPackage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const CheckoutForm = ({ selectedPackage, setSelectedPackage }: CheckoutFormProps) => {

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/checkout_sessions', { packageId: selectedPackage });
      const clientSecret = response.data.clientSecret;

      const { error } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret);

      if (error) {
        console.log('[error]', error);
      } else {
        // Payment processed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        {packages.map((pkg) => (
          <div key={pkg.id}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={pkg.id}
              name="package"
              value={pkg.id}
              checked={selectedPackage === pkg.id}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedPackage(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label htmlFor={pkg.id}>{pkg.name}: {pkg.description}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
        <PaymentElement />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe || !elements || isLoading}>
          {isLoading ? 'Processing…' : 'Pay'}
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  };

export default PaymentsPage;
```

Server code

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import Stripe from 'stripe';



const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY;
if (!stripeSecretKey) {
  throw new Error('The STRIPE_SECRET_KEY environment variable is not set.');
}

const stripe = new Stripe(stripeSecretKey, {
  apiVersion: '2023-10-16',
});

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const { packageId } = req.body;
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: packageId,
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/canceled`,
    });

    // Here we obtain the PaymentIntent's clientSecret from the session
    if (typeof session.payment_intent === 'string') {
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(session.payment_intent as string);
      res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id, clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
    } else {
      // Handle the case where payment_intent is null (e.g., log an error or throw an exception)
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'PaymentIntent is null' });
    }
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      // Now we check if it's a Stripe error
      if ("statusCode" in err && "message" in err) {
        // Here we're assuming that if the error has statusCode, it's a Stripe error.
        // We cast the error type to any to access the statusCode and message properties.
        res.status((err as any).statusCode || 500).json({ error: err.message });
      } else {
        // If it's not a Stripe error, we return a generic error response
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred' });
      }
    } else {
      // If it's not an Error instance, handle accordingly
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred' });
    }
  }


};
```

ClientSecret is not reaching front end for some reason. I am unsure whether server even receives it from Stripe in the first place. Or whether server has trouble sending it to front end. Please help me figure this out as I have had no progress for a while.

I have attached both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Stripe API version [2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01), A PaymentIntent is no longer created during Checkout Session creation in payment mode. Instead, a PaymentIntent will be created when the Session is confirmed. If you are using an API version > 2022-08-01, the checkout session won't create a PaymentIntent until it's confirmed.

You might want to use [Invoicing API](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing), or PaymentIntent API directly for your integration.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much! That helped fix my issue and the stripe integration works now. Again, Thanks!